# Ubuntu 22.04 Server - Phpmyadmin automatically upgrading php from 7.4 to 8.1

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-22.04

I am purposely downgrading php to 7.4 on our server because there are important apps like mediawiki that do not yet fully support 8.1

Yet when I install phpmyadmin, I find my PHP version has been increased to 8.1.   Any idea how to stop this behavior from happening when installing from the Ubuntu repos ie; apt-get install phpmyadmim ?